# How to clear browser's cache and cookies from terminal

Tags: browser

I want to clear my *firefox cache and cookies* from terminal.
What can i do?

Comment: I just tried deleting everything from the preferences menu, and it deleted web content cache, you just have to choose everything, close the windows.  Once open again the cache was 0.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To clean the cookies from terminal you can use the following command:

```
rm ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/cookies.sqlite
```

To clean all the cache, you can use:

```
rm ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/*.sqlite ~/.mozilla/firefox/*default/sessionstore.js
rm -r ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/*.default/*
```

But, better you can make a backup of these files if you want to restore them latter:

```
mkdir -p ~/.mozilla/firefox/backup ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/backup
mv ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/*.sqlite  ~/.mozilla/firefox/backup
mv ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/sessionstore.js ~/.mozilla/firefox/backup
mv ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/*.default/* ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/backup
```

Comment: It clears all my browser's history,weblogins etc.But it still shows `your web content cache is currently using 30 MB of disk space` under Network Tab after restarting the browser.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Ah, sorry, see my new edits.

Comment: `rm -r ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/*.default/*` command shows no such file or directory.There was no mozilla folder inside `.cache` directory.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Probably you deleted already.

Comment: In Mint Mate the command differ a little bit:
mkdir -p ~/.mozilla/firefox/backup ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/backup <br>    
mv ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default*/*.sqlite  ~/.mozilla/firefox/backup <p>    
mv ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default*/sessionstore.jsonlz4 ~/.mozilla/firefox/backup <p>    
mv ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/*.default*/* ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/backup<p>

Answer (score 5):

I would like to weigh in on this issue.  I have set Firefox to automatically clear all cache, cookies, etc., when I quit.

Firefox menu: Edit > Preferences > Privacy

History: Select "Use Custom Settings for History"

- All items are checked
- Always accept all cookies, but keep until I close Firefox
- Clear history when FF closes:  Settings:  Everything is checked except Delete Saved Passwords.

If I want to clear the history, etc. while Firefox is running, I simply hit Ctrl-Shift-Delete and choose what to delete.

If Firefox is NOT running, then there is no need to run the script, as the offending stuff has already been deleted.    **ALMOST.**  Turns out all the thumbnails are still resident in `~/.cache/thumbnails/normal` and `~/.cache/thumbnails/fail`.  For these, I wrote a little script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "shredding cache"
find ~/.cache/thumbnails -type f -name "*.png" -exec shred -f -u -z -n 1 {} \;
echo "finished shredding"
```

I fire that on a cronjob, every 3 hours.

But an even simpler way is to run bleachbit.  Just as fast to click bleachbit off the menu as it is to open a terminal and run a script.  For me, anyway.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of clearing the Firefox's cache (execute as a user, not root):

```
$ rm -rf ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/????????.*/cache2/*
```

The proper way of clearing the Firefox's cookies (execute as a user, not root):

```
$ rm ~/.mozilla/firefox/????????.*/cookies.sqlite
```

Works for both Debian and Ubuntu.

Works for multiple Firefox user profiles.

Answer (score -2):

I at least found a proper solution:

1. First go to your home location
2. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>
3. Open folder `.cache`
4. Open folder `mozilla`
5. Open folder `firefox`
6. Open the (anything).default folder
7. Open the cache folder
8. Delete all folders in this
9. Then open Firefox
10. Go to edit, preferences and delete all cache and cookies once

and i assure u the your problem will be solved

Comment: OP wants to use the terminal and not a file manager. So your answer doesn't apply.