# avoid restoration of resource-intensive Firefox session?

Tags: firefox, session

I somehow ended up with a Firefox session that takes up my entire memory and swap space and then crashes.  And then when I start up the software again the whole process repeats.  I'd like to be able to open Firefox normally without it crashing.

I found this question on clearing the cache ([How to clear browser's cache and cookies from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368325/how-to-clear-browsers-cache-and-cookies-from-terminal)), which I imagine would work, but I don't want to risk losing data that I might actually want.  I don't particularly want to lose cache or cookies; I just want Firefox to stop trying to restore all those tabs.

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Locate the file `sessionstore.js` inside your Mozilla Firefox profile folder while Firefox isn't running and delete it. This will delete your session data and nothing else.

As a one-liner:

```
find ~/.mozilla/firefox -iname sessionstore.js -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try `--safe-mode` or `--ProfileManager` to create a new profile altogether while you test backups from `~/.mozilla/firefox/YOURPROFILE/sessionstore-backups/`