# How do I delete cookies from a specific site?

Tags: firefox

[This](https://askubuntu.com/q/368325/743263) question asks how to delete *all* Firefox cookies and cache, but I need to delete cookies from a specific site. How do I do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to *Preferences* -> *Privacy & Security* -> *Cookies and Site Data* then click on the *Manage Data* button then search for the site. 
Click on the site(s) to select and click on *Remove Selected*, then *Save Changes*.

That's all you need to do.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `sqlite3` to delete cookies from terminal (Install if necessary: `sudo apt install sqlite3`)

```
sqlite3 ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/cookies.sqlite \
'delete from moz_cookies where baseDomain="example.com";'
```

or

```
sqlite3 ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/cookies.sqlite \
'delete from moz_cookies where baseDomain LIKE "%google.%";'
```

---

To delete history for a specific site:

```
sqlite3 ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/places.sqlite \
'
delete from moz_historyvisits where place_id in (select h.place_id from moz_historyvisits h join moz_places p on h.place_id = p.id where p.url like "%example.com/%");
delete from moz_places where url like "%example.com/%";
'
```

There are some more interesting tables and you might need to delete from e.g. `moz_origins`, `moz_bookmarks` or `moz_bookmarks_deleted` to remove more trails from a domain.

---

> Note: Firefox must be closed, or you will see an error message:
>
> ```
> Error: database is locked
> ```

Comment: Do you know of a similar command to delete history for a given domain? I went to remove history for a search engine after years of use and opened the GUI and pressed delete and it took 3 hours while the GUI was hung to delete all the history.

Comment: It's saved in places.sqlite, but this is a bit more complex and you need to join two tables. I added how to do it.

Comment: Though it's probably fine in practice, it might be worth mentioning that this would also delete history from sites with URLs like `https://foo.com/example.com/` and `https://foo.com/bar?baz=example.com/`

Answer (score 4):

See "manage data" in "options" and "privacy and security". It will show a list of sites with cookies; you can delete a single one from the list.

[image]

Comment: This is the right answer - but would be humblesome, by backtracking data-floods to delete one single certain cookie manually. Ghostery as add-on is taking over this for you.

Answer (score 4):

There's an even easier way, when you click the padlock on address bar, there's a "Clear cookies and site data" button:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> you will get the Clear browsing data select cookies and other site data click on Clear data.

Answer (score 2):

### One-click solution

Here's a quick and handy method I use often:

Save the following JavaScript code as a [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet), visit the site you want to clear all cookies of, and simply click on it:

```
javascript:(function(){C=document.cookie.split(&quot;; &quot;);for(d=&quot;.&quot;+location.host;d;d=(&quot;&quot;+d).substr(1).match(/\..*$/))for(sl=0;sl<2;++sl)for(p=&quot;/&quot;+location.pathname;p;p=p.substring(0,p.lastIndexOf('/')))for(i in C)if(c=C[i]){document.cookie=c+&quot;; domain=&quot;+d.slice(sl)+&quot;; path=&quot;+p.slice(1)+&quot;/&quot;+&quot;; expires=&quot;+new Date((new Date).getTime()-1e11).toGMTString()}})()
```

**[Click here to make the process easier!](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jptzdeak/1/show/)** | [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jptzdeak/1/)

---

Bookmarklet source: https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/zap.html

Comment: Does this work for `HTMLonly` cookies?

Comment: Does this work for cookies with path?

Answer (score 2):

To save energy and time, you could install an add-on for this. Then you dont need to clear the cache of cookies manually any more.
In FF browser go to menu in right corner above. Select "add-ons" and type as search word there above "cookie blocker" - so you have the free choice for data-protection of your privacy. There you can install for example "Ghostery" as add-on, then adjust it to your needs.